# How to get and bind the value of Slider in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, kinect

I can get the value of slider here:

```
    public void TheSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {


        int k = (int)TheSlider.Value;

        Debug.WriteLine(k);

    }
```

In this part, I cant get the value, so I cant use it :

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       _runtime.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle = (int)TheSlider.Value;
    }
```

This is the slider code in xaml:

```
    <Slider x:Name="TheSlider"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            Minimum="-27"
            Maximum="27"
            Cursor="Hand"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            Margin="322,392,329,87" ValueChanged="TheSlider_ValueChanged" Width="144" />
```

What is the problem here? Can you help me please?

UPDATE:

```
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        System.Windows.Data.Binding b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding();
        b.ElementName = "TheSlider";
        b.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
        SetBinding(ElevationAngleProperty, b);

    }

    public int ElevationAngle
    {
        get { return _runtime.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle; }

        set { _runtime.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle = value; OnPropertyChanged("ElevationAngle"); }
    }


    public DependencyProperty ElevationAngleProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well... you are not really binding, as we know it in WPF. For now you can change your ElevationAngle inside the method TheSlider_ValueChanged.

Comment: I did it, but when I do it inside the method TheSlider_ValueChanged, it stops running the application. ElevationAngle has to be inside Window_Loaded. :S

Comment: That sounds really weird. Has any error reported?

Comment: @NestorArturo When I create a button and If I say inside the button method " _runtime.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle = (int)TheSlider.Value; ", it works. It sets it. But If I try to do with just slider, application says error encountered and there is no error explanation, it closes the application. 

So, I could do it with button and slider, but not with just slider.

Answer (score 9):

When I just want to set the value of my sliders as content of a Label, I simply go with this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}"/>
```

When you want to show the value as an integer you just have to save your value everytime your slider changes its value.

```
<Slider  Name="mySlider" ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged" />

...
this.sliderValue = (int) mySlider.Value;
```

Then bind the content of your label to it.

Answer (score 0):

If ElevationAngle is a dependency property,You can directly bind dependency property to the slider value.

Do this in OnApplyTemplate function

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.ElementName = "TheSlider";
            b.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
            SetBinding(ElevationAngleProperty, b);

        }
```

If it is regular CLR property then bind value property of slider with ElevationAngle

```
       <Slider x:Name="TheSlider"                     DockPanel.Dock="Left"                     Orientation="Horizontal"                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"                     Minimum="-27"                     Maximum="27"                     Cursor="Hand"                     IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"                     Margin="322,392,329,87" ValueChanged="TheSlider_ValueChanged" Width="144" Value="{Binding Path=ElevationAngle,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
/>
```

Note that here ElevationAngle should send notification when changed

```
public int ElevationAngle 
        {
            get { return _elevationAngle ; }

            set { _elevationAngle  = value; OnPropertyChanged("ElevationAngle ");}
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting errors from your code at  SetBinding(ElevationAngleProperty, b);   and    OnPropertyChanged("ElevationAngle "); Can you check Update above in my code please? Where do I do wrong ?

Comment: Hi Sameet, you seem to be using both the solution together.
Instead of creating ElevationAngleProperty , simply bind the value of slider to ElevationAngle . It should work.

Steps:

1.delete OnApplyTemplate funtion and ElevationAngleProperty 
2. Bind Slider Value to ElevationAngle